# jQuery - get neighborhood element

Tags: jquery

I need to get neighborhood element value.

HTML is

```
<div>
    <input type='hidden' value='12345'>
    <div id='click-this'>Click me</div>
</div>
```

How can i get "12345" by clicking "click-this" div ?

```
$('#click-this').click(function() {
    /* 
     * Get siblings element's: 
     * at this context, input tag element with value 12345 
     *
     */  

})
```

Answer (score 20, accepted):

You could do this in multiple ways, but the word neighborhood suggests you could use [siblings](http://api.jquery.com/siblings/):

```
$('#click-this').siblings('input').val();
```

Answer (score 4):

I haven't tested this but try: (based on documentation of jQuery 1.4.2)

```
$('#click-this').click(function() {
   alert($(this).prev().val());
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Few more ways :-

```
$('#click-this').click(function() {
    var value = $(this).parent().children().eq(0).attr('value'); 
                      or
    var value = $(this).parent().children().eq(0).val(); 
});
```